# .NET Core 2.2 Identity write to additional table on CreateAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I've added an additional table to the default Identity schema called `UserProfile`, which contains things like address information.
 When a new user registers on the site, I would like to add the users to the default `IdentityUser` table, add user roles to the
 default `UserRoles` table, and add the additional user info to my new `UserProfile` table. I have this currently setup as shown in the pseudocode
below. The insert `User` and `UserRoles` uses the default idenitity methods, and I wrote my own methods for the `UserProfile` insert. Basically this is happening with three different insert transactions. If there is a failure on any of the three insert transaction, it then executes individual `Delete()` transactions.
While this does work for me, I'm guessing there is a more elegant way to do this?

```
 CreateUser()

 if CreateUser == success
 {
    AddUserRoles()

    if AddRoles == success
    {
        AddUserProfile()

        if AddUserProfile != success
        {
            DeleteUserRoles()
            DeleteUser()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DeleteUser()
    }
 }
```

**ACTUAL CODE**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
        var userResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

        if (userResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);
            var roleResult = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(currentUser, roles);

            if (roleResult.Succeeded)
            {
                var profileSuccess = _userRepo.AddUserProfile(currentUser.Id);

                if (profileSuccess)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./RegisterConfirmation", new { email = user.Email });
                }
                else
                {
                    await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
                    await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            }  
        }
    }

    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: Post, minimal example to specify how are you using Identity.   Also, are you using userManager instance for creating user ?

Comment: I have added the code